# How to split outputs of single column with awk?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I want to grep out Port and IP address from `netstat -tulpn` command.
Output is like this :

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN              
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN           
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:5334          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6113          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:601                 :::*                    LISTEN            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5013            0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:5333          0.0.0.0:*                               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6341            0.0.0.0:*                           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53553           0.0.0.0:*                                
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5123            0.0.0.0:*                           
udp6       0      0 :::4905                 :::*                                
udp6       0      0 :::353                  :::*
```

With `awk` I get Local Address column.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | awk '{ print $4;}'
```

Now I just want to split Port and IP from each other and show in two separate columns. What's the simplest way to do it? (*regex* or somthing like that)

Comment: What's wrong with using awk's `split()` function?

Comment: Thank you Barmar,I not familiar with awk functions.But google it to find out way.And done with : sudo netstat -tulpn | awk '{split($4,a,":"); print a[1];}' for IP , And sudo netstat -tulpn | awk '{split($4,a,":"); print a[2];}' to get Ports columns.Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split on the *last* colon in that field. With GNU awk:

```
gawk '{match($4, /(.*):(.*)/, m); print m[1], m[2]}'
```

or

```
gawk '{print gensub(/(.*):/,"\\1 ", 1, $4)}'
```

With a non-GNU awk:

```
mawk '{ip=$4; sub(/:[^:]+/,"",ip); port=$4; sub(/.*:/,"",port); print ip,port}'
```

With perl

```
perl -lapE '$_ = join(" ", $F[3] =~ /(.*):(.*)/)'
```

Pipe the output into `| column -t` to make it pretty.